# API Store in WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is the API Store still accessible in WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0? I can't seem to access it at `https://localhost:9443/store`. Has it been replaced or can it still be accessed? If so how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been replaced, apparently, by the developer portal which can now be accessed with  `https://localhost:9443/devportal`

Source: WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0 Documentation